# Converted dimmers causing circuit issues

Tags: electrical, wiring, ceiling-fan, dimmer-switch

A friend of mine called me over to help with an issue he had and I couldn’t help.  He currently has a ceiling fan and two lights on the same circuit (possibly more). The two lights are controlled by separate dimmers. Everything worked fine before he converted to the wire style dimmers (Lutron). Since switching (diagram 2), the lights work independently, but when one is on the ceiling fan light no longer works (despite having power to the fixture).  The prior wiring (diagram 1) had a daisy chain(?) running from one switch to another and I don’t know how to recreate that with the wire style dimmers. Is it even possible?  Thanks.
[image: original wiring diagram]
[image: current wiring diagram that is causing issues somewhere]

Comment: Often, these dimmers can work in 2-way and 3-way circuits. If yours is one of those, make sure you've connected the correct wires. Make sure you've got the hot supply (black) connected to the LINE connection on both switches, then make sure you're using the LOAD wire, not the TRAVELER wire from the switches.

Comment: So that’s the rub. If you look at diagram one there was a hot line jumping from one switch to the other. I do not understand what role this wire had.  As far as I’m concerned we have it wired exactly the same but now we are interrupting the circuit somehow.

Comment: In my experience, diagrams show what we _intended_ to do, while pictures show what we _actually_ did. Please pull these out of the wall _without_ disconnecting wires and give us a couple of clear, focused, well lit pictures showing exactly what you've done. Also brand/model of the switches in question and a picture of (or even better a link to) the installation instructions. With that, I'm sure someone will be able to point you in the right direction. Without that, we're left guessing, just like you are.

Comment: Freeman - I figured it out. The LED light fixtures he installed were interfering with the RF signal to the ceiling fan. Thats why it would not turn on when the light was on. We tested the theory by putting the remote right on the receiver and it switched right on. Wild.

Comment: Please write that up as an answer, then in 48 hours, come back and click the check mark to indicate that this question has a solution. That's the accepted way of doing things here - editing the title to indicate "solved" very much is _NOT_ the way to do it. If you just leave that in the comments, this will linger for years and the next person may never notice that there's a solution. If you'll spend a few moments to take the [tour], you'll learn that and other great stuff.

Comment: The solution to this problem ended up being not related to the wiring at all. If you run into a similar issue look into led lighting and RF interference. In this situation, one of the led fixtures was only about 6’ from the ceiling fan. The led fixture when powered on was interrupting the RF signal from the remote to the ceiling fan. This can apparently impact televisions and other devices that use RF remotes so if you run into the issue - you can quickly test this by placing the remote directly on the receiver and seeing if the interference is indeed the issue.

Comment: That's not the point. The point is that this info should be entered down below in the box labeled "Your Answer", not buried in a comment that can be overlooked or even easily deleted in the future. By leaving it buried in the comments it's much more difficult for others who may be experiencing the exact same issue that you had to find the answer. They may find your question _title_ in a search, but see that it has zero answers and move on without even reading the question itself, to say nothing about looking through the comments.

Comment: You can be extra helpful by sharing your information with others in the way that this site is designed to share info, not in the way you choose to do so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this problem ended up being not related to the wiring at all. If you run into a similar issue look into led lighting and RF interference. In this situation, one of the led fixtures was only about 6’ from the ceiling fan. The led fixture when powered on was interrupting the RF signal from the remote to the ceiling fan. This can apparently impact televisions and other devices that use RF remotes so if you run into the issue - you can quickly test this by placing the remote directly on the receiver and seeing if the interference is indeed the issue.

Comment: Thanks for stopping back by to provide an answer - greatly appreciated! +1

Comment: Try switching to a "garage door" rated LED bulb if you're having RFI issues with the current batch